# Rar Password Unlocker crashing with rockyou

Tags: password-recovery, rar

I am trying to use Rar Password Unlcoker with the Rockyou dictionary to unlock a file. Unlocker works with smaller dictionaries and brute force. As soon as I use the 140MB Rockyou list however I get the message "Rar Password Unlocker has stopped working" and am forced to close the program. I have closed all programs on my computer (a Lenovo AMD notebook) except file explorer, have 4 GB ram and am running Windows 8. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a question about security. I'll migrate it to a site which may be able to help.

Comment: The program is probably just unstable. Have a Google about for a better one :)